# Trouble accessing Mutable array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting, object

Im having trouble reassigning data in an array where I am trying to index user names. I am able to separate my original array into individual objects but am not able to send the value to a new array that I need to reference later on. The value and count for userNames in my `self.userNamesArray = userNames;` line is correct. But right after that when I log self.userNamesArray, I get (null). Any tips cause I'm not completely sure I'm  cheers!

.h

`@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *userNamesArray;`

.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

self.friendsRelation = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"friendsRelation"];

PFQuery *query = [self.friendsRelation query];
[query orderByAscending:@"username"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
    else {
        self.friends = objects;

        NSArray *users = [self.friends valueForKey:@"username"];
        NSLog(@"username:%@", users);
        //Create an array of name wrappers and pass to the root view controller.
        NSMutableArray *userNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[self.friends count]];

        for (NSString *user in users) {

        componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charSet];
            NSArray *nameComponents = [user componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

            UserNameWrapper *userNameWrapper = [[UserNameWrapper alloc]    initWithUserName:nil nameComponents:nameComponents];

            [userNames addObject:userNameWrapper];
        }

        self.userNamesArray = userNames;

        NSLog(@"userNamesArray:%@",self.userNamesArray);

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

Here's the code where I need to reference the self.userNamesArray where again, it is comping up nil.

```
- (void)setUserNamesArray:(NSMutableArray *)newDataArray {

if (newDataArray != self.userNamesArray) {
    self.userNamesArray = [newDataArray mutableCopy];
    if (self.userNamesArray == nil) {
        self.sectionsArray = nil;
        NSLog(@"user names empty");
    }
    else {
        [self configureSections];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please add the language tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your property method of mutable array to below:-

```
    @property (nonatomic, retain) 
    NSMutableArray *userNamesArray;
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried that too but the results are still the same.

Comment: Change this line inside viewwillappear and check [self setUserNamesArray:[NSArray arrayWithObject:userNames]];

Comment: Tried that and am now getting this error thrown: `-[__NSArrayM userName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1568fb50` Ive been trying to solve this all day. Maybe I'm just too tired.

Comment: Sorry my mistake replace nsarray arraywithobject to nsmutablearray arraywithobject

Comment: I was able to get passed the line that was throwing the error and set the value for my userNamesArray with your suggestions! (just needed a bit of sleep) I'm still getting the 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error, but that's a whole other question.

Answer (score 1):

Is this code calling itself recursively?

```
self.userNamesArray = [newDataArray mutableCopy];
```

is equivilent to:

```
[self setUserNamesArray: [newDataArray mutableCopy]];
```

If you need to override what happens during assignment, you can do as you're doing here but use _userNamesArray to reference the underlying member field.

Comment: I had tried using _userNamesArray reference but the system was throwing a Bad Access error for this line `self.userNamesArray = [newDataArray mutableCopy];`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't you need NSMutableArray for "userNamesArray". You could simply use NSArray. Now, try with below piece of code and you should be good to go:

```
self.userNamesArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:userNames];
```

Answer (score 0):

You might get null because of this line:

`NSArray *users = [self.friends valueForKey:@"username"];`

Change it to:

`NSArray *users = [self.friends objectForKey:@"username"];`

In addition, follow @Abhinav suggestion to have more cleaner code :)